# Pass props to children directly

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass my props right to my children's component.

I don't want to pass them to children and then to a decomposition component. I want to make it easier and faster.

I wondered, is it okay if I pass my props this way? Everything works as intended.

Or do I break some unknown for me rules? If I break them what can happen otherwise? If I don't break them and it's the bad approach anyway, please, explain to me why?

```
export function ParentComponent() {
  const [myProp, setMyProp] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildrenComponent>
        // Nested component gets props right here
        <DecompositionComponent myProp={myProp} setMyProp={setMyProp} />
      </ChildrenComponent>
    </div>
  );
```

[Link to a code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pass-props-to-children-directly-tpqjnw?file=/src/components/ParentComponent.js)

P.S. I know about "render props" and useContext.

Comment: Is something not working in the code shown?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is the code shown what you're asking about, or what you want to avoid?

Comment: I was wondering if I pass props this way it breaks some rules or it's an allowable way

Comment: It's "allowable" because it's possible--that's a self-answering question ;) That said, there's nothing unusual about this at **all**, it's very, very common.

Comment: > it's very, very common. > Anyway I didn't watch examples like this either in projects or in articles

Comment: @DaveNewton Could u gimme a link to some resource?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly valid way of sending props to components with component composition. It's also a powerful pattern to use as it can make your components more reusable, and you avoid deep prop drilling.

Comment: Thank you, man. It's good to read it